# RSpec failure: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm walking through a book (Rails 4 in Action v14 MEAP) and have encountered an error when running my spec:

```
Failures:

  1) Creating Projects can create a project
     Failure/Error: click_button 'Create Project'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/projects/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__1338549725163946383_70209940313300'
     # ./spec/features/creating_projects_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.23155 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/creating_projects_spec.rb:4 # Creating Projects can create a project
```

I've been searching online and through the book and have been following the instructions. I can't seem to find my mistake. The book (where I'm currently at on page 91) says that I should be receiving the following error instead:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Project has been created.')
  expected there to be text "Project has been created." in "TextMate 2"
```

My repo for the project is at http://github.com/freqn/ticketee

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `show` method of your controller you set the instance variable `@projects` (plural)

```
def show
  @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

In the `show` view you use the instance variable `@project` (singular).

```
<h2><%= @project.name %></h2>
```

As a result of this, there is no instance variable `@project`, so when the view tries to call the `name` method it's actually doing `nil.name`, hence the `undefined method` error.

Change your controller method:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])     # @project instead of @projects
end
```

Comment: Thank you.. I thought I was overlooking something simple. Once I can validate, I'll mark this as the accepted answer